# Using ModelBuilder and Raster Calculator with Output Location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1 ModelBuilder to create a tool that calculates the surface temperature using with base a landsat 8 bands. The tool is working fine, my parameters are working well and inputs too.

My only problem is that I want to the system be most automated as I can, and I want the user to be capable to set the output location of the files and its name. Using another tool's at ModelBuilder I checked that is easy to add it as model parameter, but at raster calculator these settings are not available.

Does somebody know how to make available to the user to set the output file location, and name using the ModelBuilder and raster calculator tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add the raster calculator to the model, right click on the output raster and tick "Model Parameter".

If this does not work, right click within the model and select "Create Variable..." and add a "raster dataset".  You can then set this as a parameter and use it in your model.

Here is a guide to using variables in modelbuilder:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-stand-alone-variables.htm